# Java FX: Stack pane children width in percentage (FXML only)

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Novice in Java FX. Trying to create the following layout:

[image]

I do not see the reason to use Grid Pane: maybe it's my mistake, but Grid pane is overkill for two child element. So, I selected the Stack Pane.

How can I set width of children to 50% and height to 100% of parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a `StackPane`; use a `HBox` and set the `HBox.hgrow` property to `ALWAYS` for both children:

```xml
<HBox fillHeight="true">
   <children>
      <TextArea HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <TextArea HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will use `HBox`, but why I should not use `Stack Pane`?

Comment: With a `StackPane` you need a binding to resize the children to half the width of the parent (in addition to setting the alignment). This is simply more complicated than using a `HBox` which takes care of not overlapping the children and can made to resize the child nodes with the same priority. Furthermore I'm not sure SceneBuilder can deal with bindings if you're using that tool...

Answer (score 1):

not enough reputation to respond to fabian, but what you should know is that StackPane is used to **stack** elements on top of each other. HBox gives each other equal portion of its width if not set otherwise. You might also want to use **SplitPane** to change width in runtime, very useful when working with two textareas

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I see, the Stack pane is completely different in UWP and JavaFX.